# Read textinput line by line and add into a list

Tags: python, list, kivy, textinput, file-read

I have a function which reads a file line by line and inserts it into a textinput:

```
    def load_list(self, path, filename):
    self.text_from_file.text = ''
    with open(filename[0], 'r') as file:
        line = file.readline()
        cnt = 1
        while line:
            sentence = "{}".format(line.strip())
            self.text_from_file.text += sentence + "\n"
            line = file.readline()
            cnt += 1

    self.dismiss_popup()
```

Now file content is stored in `text_from_file` variable, which is `text_from_file = ObjectProperty(None)` type (I am using kivy).

What I want to do is read the text from `textinput` (`text_from_file.text`) and add every line into a list, so one line will be one item in the list. How can I read `textinput` line by line? Does it work the same as from file? I do not want to do it right away in the function above. I want to do it later in a separate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to get all lines from a file into a list is like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f]

# do something with lines
```

EDIT:

To read a variable line by line, just split it by '\n' and iterate over the result:

```
for line in self.text_from_file.text.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: But I need to read from `text_from_file` variable, which is `textinput` type. So I already have text from the file stored.

Comment: Oh okay. Edited the answer.